# Is there a way to subtract one result from the previous result?

Tags: python, subtraction

I'm trying to answer a book problem given by my teacher and I'm having trouble finding a way to subtract a previous result with the next result. The problem asks for a loop of results until the previous result subtracted by the next result has a tolerance of 1e-10. 
The equation is :

> H+ = sqrt(Ka * (c - n))
>
> in which Ka = 1.78e−5
>
> c = 0.01
>
> n = starts at zero

The iterations are continued until H+ changes by less than some predetermined, small tolerance value, in this case TOL = 1e-10.

I've looked some of the questions based on things like this in here, since I'm extremely new to python coding (less than a month working with it) but i haven't found anything that was useful for this, since most of them you get a column and then subtract the results from that like this one ([How to subtract from previous row result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899341/how-to-subtract-from-previous-row-result)), but I can't do that.

```
n = 0
Ka = 1.78e-5
c = 0.01
q = Ka * (c - n)

H = q ** 0.5
H1 = q ** 0.5

while n < 10:
     print(H)
     if (H1 - H == 1e-10):
         break
```

This is what I managed to make but it keeps me giving endless results because I don't know how to subtract the previous result from the next result. Can someone please shed some light in this?

Comment: You need to update the `H1` value with the current `H` value each iteration of the loop where the _absolute value of the difference_ is not _less than or equal_ to the tolerance. You also need to increment the `n` value by `1`.

Comment: perform your computations in the loop, and use `for n in range(10)` as well.

Comment: Also note that due to [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), inside the loop you'll need to compute the value using `(Ka * (c - n)) ** 0.5` (assuming you don't calculate a `q` value separately like you did initially).